# Reorganization WordPress boxes in admin area

Tags: php, wordpress

Actually, I have two questions here.

**1:** How to hide some boxes in **WordPress** area (for example, categories box or comments box) for subscribers?

**2:** How to sort categories in category box by id (looks like, by default, it sorted by name). For example, I would like to see

```
the next order: 1, 2, 3...
but not 10, 1, 11
```

[image: here]

Comment: You may find better answers over at the wordpress exchange.  This site is specific to programming so if you don't have actual code examples of what you have tried so far, most people will ignore this question.  Here is the link to the wordpress exchange:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

For Question-1,
Add code as per below in your active theme's functions.php file

```
function my_remove_meta_boxes() {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        /**
         * arg-1 : id of the metabox, arg-2: page or posttype, arg-3: screen where the boxes displaying
         */
        remove_meta_box( 'tagsdiv-stages', 'post', 'side' ); // as per my page https://www.screencast.com/t/VCnvf61M7ydS
        remove_meta_box( 'commentsdiv', 'post', 'normal' );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_remove_meta_boxes' );
```

You can refer : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box

Answer (score 0):

For Question-2,
Please Try below code.

```
function sort_get_terms_args( $args, $taxonomies ) {
    global $pagenow;
    if( !is_admin() || ('post.php' != $pagenow && 'post-new.php' != $pagenow) ) 
        return $args;

    $args['orderby'] = 'term_id';
    $args['order'] = 'ASC';

    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'get_terms_args', 'sort_get_terms_args', 10, 2 );
```

Hope this will helpful for you !

Comment: Thank you very much, but how to apply this functionality only for specific taxonomy, not for all taxonomies?

Comment: Please try below one and let me know It's working or not,

function sort_get_terms_args( $args, $taxonomies ) {
    global $pagenow;
    if( !is_admin() || ('post.php' != $pagenow && 'post-new.php' != $pagenow) ) 
        return $args;
    
    if($args['taxonomy'] == "taxonomy name"){
        $args['orderby'] = 'term_id';
        $args['order'] = 'ASC';
    }

    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'get_terms_args', 'sort_get_terms_args', 10, 2 );